# Passing HTML element as a prop with other props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where I need to pass a HTML element as a prop to another element

```
const MyText = () => {
     return (
          <>
               <h1>Sample heading</h1>
          </>
     )
}

return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent Text={MyText} onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={show} />
    </div>
  );
```

MyComponent.js

```
export default function MyComponent(props) {
  return (
    <>
    {props.Text}
    </>
  );
}
```

Issue: I'm not getting anything rendered on the screen. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You need so pass `MyText` as a component not a function -> `Text={<MyText/>}`. See [Composition vs Inheritance](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: This also sounds a little unnecessarily complicated. Components should (ideally) be as dumb as possible. Can't you just pass in the text and let the component render it inside the heading?

Comment: @Andy I would agree with you if this is what his production code looks like, but it appears to be simplified code for demonstration purposes and the heading thing is properly just there as an example.

Comment: I would ask "why" even if it wasn't production code. @MatthewKwong. Or perhaps, "what is the problem the OP is trying to solve?".

Comment: @Andy Well, the "problem" is literally in the question itself. He wants to pass a component/HTML element to another component through props and render it.

Comment: If I was running a code review on this my question would still be "why?"

Comment: @Andy thanks for sharing your feedback.
The sample <MyComponent> is a reusable component that takes HTML elements as props and displays them using a modal popup.
Since the reusable component is expecting only HTML elements as props, I was curious to know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

Option 1: Passing a component type (or class if you are coming from OOP background)

```
const MyText = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Sample heading</h1>
    </>
  )
}

return (
  <div>
    <MyComponent Text={MyText} onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={show} />
  </div>
);


const MyComponent = ({ Text }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Text />
    </>
  );
}
```

Option 2: Passing a component (or instance if you are coming from OOP background)

```
const MyText = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Sample heading</h1>
    </>
  )
}

return (
  <div>
    <MyComponent text={<MyText />} onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={show} />
  </div>
);


const MyComponent = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {text}
    </>
  );
}
```